# Eclipse Android - strange error with try/catch block

Tags: java, android, eclipse, try-catch

i wanted to programm an app for android, but i get an error with my code and i don't understand what should be wrong with it.

Because i'm new here i cannot post images, but an image describes the error best i think.
[eclipse error pic](http://s22.postimg.org/5mib157oh/eclipse_error.jpg)

And here is the Code if someone dont trusts the link

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient;

public class Connection {
    private static final String TAG = null;
    final SSHClient ssh = new SSHClient();
     byte[] ipAddr = {};

    try {ssh.connect(InetAddress.getByAddress(ipAddr));
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){

    }
}
```

Correct me if i'm wrong but i think this is a bug somewhere or what am i missing here? I'm new to android programming, but with java i'm very familiar and for me the code looks valid.

I hope that someone can help me out.

Comment: You don't have any method..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is directly inside class. It should be inside method.

Comment: OMG, thank so much! I must be blind too not see this. It gives no excuses for this. Maybe i'm only too tired for programming today ;)

Answer (score 1):

Place your try-catch code inside a method; it's not currently in a method.

Answer (score 0):

the problem lies

here

byte[] ipAddr = {};

i faced a similar issue this afternoon!

there should be something between the {};
or you couldve just written

byte[] ipAddr;

Comment: thank you too, and see my comment above ;)